# recovering android wallet using opensll

Tags: recover-private-key

i am very frustrated, i managed to decrypt the backup file by doing the opensll command and as expected after putting the password i do see org.bitcoin.production which means i am at the right path but it also gives me 2 lines of some alien language which i dont know what to do with, i am not able to do the bitcoinj thing as all the opensll commands i see in the forums by schibald to get the wallet tool are saying invalid commands. so pls help me

Comment: Please help us to help you. Edit your question and add in a cut and paste of the commands you type in and the exact full error messages you received

Comment: i am not able to copy anything from the openssl page, but i have entered "enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in bitcoin-wallet-backup-testnet-2014-11-01" and then the password so it does say org.bitcoin.production and after this its giving an alien language with some letter and numbers in between. so whats next, how to get the private keys from here ?